# Getting the error that I need to have writer access to this calendar. (Google::Apis::ClientError)

Tags: ruby, google-api, google-calendar-api

**RESOLVED**

The changes to Google Workspace calendar sharing settings took about 2 hours to come into effect.

The fix is to share the calendar with the service account and give it permission to manage events.

I keep getting the "You need to have writer access to this calendar. (Google::Apis::ClientError)" error when trying to create an event through a script.

I have done and ensured the following:

- The service account has domain wide access in Google Workspace
- Confirmed that it has the correct auth access too (
- The service account has "Editor" role and permissions on Google Cloud
- Google Workspace setting for sharing calendars is allowed for external emails

I am at a loss currently and would appreciate any advice.

Code is as follows:

```
OOB_URI = 'urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob'
CREDENTIALS_PATH = File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'credentials.json')
SCOPE = Google::Apis::CalendarV3::AUTH_CALENDAR_EVENTS
APPLICATION_NAME = "GCAL Events"


def authorize
    credentials = Google::Auth::ServiceAccountCredentials.make_creds(
      json_key_io: File.open(CREDENTIALS_PATH),
      scope: SCOPE
    )
    credentials.fetch_access_token!
    credentials
    
  end


  def create_event(summary, start_time, end_time)
    service = Google::Apis::CalendarV3::CalendarService.new
    service.client_options.application_name = APPLICATION_NAME
    service.authorization = authorize
  
    event = Google::Apis::CalendarV3::Event.new({
      summary: summary,
      start: {
        date_time: start_time,
        time_zone: 'Pacific/Auckland'
      },
      end: {
        date_time: end_time,
        time_zone: 'Pacific/Auckland'
      }
    })
  
    
    result = service.insert_event('email@mydomain.com', event)
    puts "Event created: #{result.html_link}"
  end

  
  create_event('xyz', '2023-03-03T09:00:00+12:00', '2023-03-03T10:00:00+12:00')
```

Create an event on a calendar of another user in Google Workspace

Comment: There are two problems with your post I would like to point out. The first is: when answering your own question, you should [post it as a self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and not as an update in the post. The second is: when posting an update to your post, do not include it at the beginning of the post. It makes it very difficult for readers to tell when your update ends and when the original post begins.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell the service account which user on the domain to delegate as.

```
authorizer = Google::Auth::ServiceAccountCredentials.make_creds(
  json_key_io: StringIO.new(File.read AppConfig[:credentials_file]),
  scope: AppConfig[:cal_scope]).dup
authorizer.sub = @person
authorizer.fetch_access_token!
```